# Change navbarmenu active background color in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some trouple finding the right css code where i can change the background color for my navigation bar when it's active. Right now it look like this:

[image]

As you can see, i'm in the about section, but no background-color when active. Have searched some post here on stack, but the code they provide in these post, haven't solved it yet.

**Code**

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img alt="searchPage" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="50px" src="images/logo.jpg" title="Start bilferien til Norge eller England" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarmiddle">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbarunder">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried all the options in my bootstrap file where it says navbar-inverse and navbar-fixed-top, but none have worked.

Have also tried this code in my Css file Site.Css, but did also not work.

```
 .nav .active a { background:#003665 !important }
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

After reading the topic , i have tried these settings in my Site.css file.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
      color: #000;
      background: #003665;
 }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > li{
    color: #000;
    background: #005184;
}

 .navbar-fixed-top .active a { 
     color: #000;
     background: #005184;
 }
```

This did also not work.. :(

Comment: Have read the topic on top, but still got problems.. the background-color just wont change.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
.navbar .nav .active {
    background-color: #005184;
}

.navbar .nav .active > a {  
    color: #000;    
    background-color: #005184;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it with my code.. because it does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

Goto http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and change the value for @navbar-default-link-active-bg. I'd adjust as many of the other colors and settings as you can then download the package.

If you don't use the custom build, at the very least you will see where the value gets used.